# QT Creator - Hex display in Locals and Expressions Window

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How to display local variable's value in Hex format in QT Creator?
Almost all the answer i found out there asks to use debug statements, convert the variable to Hex and use printf or other code snippets.
But as a matter of fact, shouldn't the IDE has some capability to display them in Hex format, or other display format user likes?

For example,

[image: QByteArray in QT Creator]

This is a stream of bytes, but meaningful to me only when shown in hex.

The same with the locals window.

[image: Locals and Expressions]

I know how to print QByteArray in hex using code, but would like to see them in Hex format in debugger locals/expressions window. Any idea?

btw, below is the current configuration.
[image: Locals And Expressions Config]

Using: QT5.10.1 QT Creator:4.5.1

Comment: Just checked my Qt Creator 4.10.1 Based on Qt 5.13.1 (Windows), and it shows both decimal and hex values along with the ASCII representation in the Value column by default: [Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/tQ86t6t/qc.png). Settings are pretty much the same: [Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/6X3d8Dw/qc-settings.png).

Comment: Seems the problem is with the CDB python dumper. Had to disable the python dumper in QTC-4.5.1 due to some other bugs. With QTC-4.10.0 the combo works (CDB+python dumper), which gives the hex visualization.